# Simple LINQ insert record not working

Tags: c#, linq, insert, datacontext

I have an .mdf file which I'm trying to add a record to, using linq in C#.
My code is:

```
dbDataContext context = new dbDataContext();
book b = new book();
b.title = "Test Book";
b.isbn = "123789";
context.books.InsertOnSubmit(b);
context.SubmitChanges();
```

When this code runs, the record is not inserted, and I get no error messages. If I use the database explorer to add a record with the *selfsame* data, it works.

What's going on?

Comment: Maybe your code runs inside a transaction that is not committed?

Comment: Does your dbDataContext point to the right database? Can you get some data out with context.books.ToList() ?

Comment: nope, it's not in a transaction

Comment: Ahh, an .mdf file. Are you using a copy in .\bin\debug but look for the results in a file in the project folder?

Comment: oh! It's suddenly working... Stupid Microsoft :P

Comment: yes, thats probably the reason. Thank you for very much for your help :)

Comment: perhaps I should look for a job in the food service industry :$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally when this happens it is indicative of the changes going to the incorrect database. Check your connection settings in your dbml. To test out the theory, try adding a record or two programmatically and if you have an identity field in that database, after context.SubmitChanges() check what the value of b.Id is (where Id is equal to your IDENTITY column). If it has a value, then you most definitely have a connection issue & you should check for another database. Pay particular attention to your bin/debug directory.

Comment: Sincere thanks for your help. I was being a douche and letting c# copy my db to the bin directory at run time, so I was basically working off a temporary copy.

Comment: haha! No worries, man. It happens to me all of the time. I've been working with the M$ Sync framework lately and had something very similar happen to me yesterday. Kept me busy for 4 hours. Lemme know if they're hiring when ya get that food service job! ;)